# Как найти ближайшую точку на окружности?

Tags: математика, геометрия, любой-язык

Есть окружность представленная в виде точки **O(X, Y)** и **радиуса R**.

Также есть другая точка **A** как найти координаты точки **B** ближайшей от **A** расположенной на окружности **O**?

Comment: Провести прямую от центра окружности к точке А и найти точку пересечения окружности и этой прямой... Формулы, надеюсь, выписывать не нужно? :)

Comment: Я как раз за формулами и пришёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто, если сначала перенести начало координат в центр окружности, решить простейшую систему уравнений, сводящуюся к извлечению корня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а потом вернуться в старую систему координат.

Если вы еще не учились примерно в 9 классе, то вот вам полное решение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решений, как видите, два. Один из знаков соответствует точке с минимальным расстоянием, второе - с максимальным. Какой именно знак для минимума, а какой для максимума - зависит от взаимного расположения точки и окружности.

Как вычислять по этим формулам и сравнивать значения, надеюсь, рассказывать не нужно?

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваша формула заработала в моём приложении, я обучаюсь в 7 классе и создаю приложение пошагово решающее и объясняющее геометрические задачи, простите если я не превношу много полезного в программистское comunity.

Comment: Нет, все нормально, просто вам надо было сразу это сказать. Ответ ведь очень сильно зависит от того, кто спрашивает :)

Answer (score 1):

Задача составить у-е прямой проходящей из через 2 точки  O(X0, Y0) и A (X1,Y1), найти B(X2,Y2) лежащая на прямой и на окружности.

1. ур-е прямой `(X-X0)/(X1-X0) = (Y-Y0)/(Y1-Y0)`

   X = (Y-Y0)*(X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + X0
2. ур-е окружноти с ценром в О радиуса  `(X – X0 )*(X – X0) + (Y – Y0)*(Y – Y0) = R*R`

подставляем X

```
((Y-Y0)*(X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + X0 - X0)*((Y-Y0)*(X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + X0 - X0) + (Y – Y0)*(Y – Y0) = R*R

(Y-Y0)*(Y-Y0)*((X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + 1) = R*R

(Y-Y0)*(Y-Y0) =  R*R/((X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + 1)

Y = R/((X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + 1)^(1/2) + Y0

X = (R/((X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + 1)^(1/2))*(X1-X0)/(Y1-Y0) + X0
```

Как то так надеюсь не ошибся.

Comment: У меня не получилось использовать эту формулу, точка идёт по дуге, но по какой-то очень большой.

Comment: `val X = (Radius / ((X1 - X0) / (Y1 - Y0) + 1f).pow(0.5f)) * (X1 - X0) / (Y1 - Y0) + X1`

Comment: `val Y = Radius / ((X1 - X0) / (Y1 - Y0) + 1f).pow(0.5f) + Y0`